# Swift Decodable - How to decode nested JSON that has been base64 encoded

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I am attempting to decode a JSON response from a third-party API which contains nested/child JSON that has been base64 encoded.

**Contrived Example JSON**

```
{
   "id": 1234,
   "attributes": "eyAibmFtZSI6ICJzb21lLXZhbHVlIiB9",  
}
```

PS `"eyAibmFtZSI6ICJzb21lLXZhbHVlIiB9"` is  `{ 'name': 'some-value' }` base64 encoded.

I have some code that is able to decode this at present but unfortunately I have to reinstanciate an additional `JSONDecoder()` inside of the `init` in order to do so, and this is not cool...

**Contrived Example Code**

```
struct Attributes: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

struct Model: Decodable {

    let id: Int64
    let attributes: Attributes

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case attributes
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.id = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .id)

        let encodedAttributesString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .attributes)

        guard let attributesData = Data(base64Encoded: encodedAttributesString) else {
            fatalError()
        }

        // HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        self.attributes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Attributes.self, from: attributesData)
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve the decoding without instanciating the additional `JSONDecoder`?

PS: I have no control over the response format and it cannot be changed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the downside with using an additional `JSONDecoder`? (and I don't think you can avoid it)

Comment: Some reasons I can think of... because the new decoder will potentially have different options to the original (e.g. `convertFromSnakeCase` or `dateDecodingStrategy`), because the data format might not be JSON at all, someone might be trying to decode the same model in an XML format.

Comment: You can put a custom decoder (could be one with the same options), in the `userInfo` of the "main" Decoder.

Comment: what @Larme said, ... and, the fact that it could be a different data format from the decoder of the parent object (e.g. XML inside a JSON) is a reason I was thinking why it ought to be an additional (or different) decoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the question interesting, so here is a possible solution which would be to give the main decoder an additional one in its `userInfo`:

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let additionalDecoder = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "AdditionalDecoder")!
}

var decoder = JSONDecoder()
let additionalDecoder = JSONDecoder() //here you can put the same one, you can add different options, same ones, etc.
decoder.userInfo = [CodingUserInfoKey.additionalDecoder: additionalDecoder]
```

Because the main method we use from `JSONDecoder()` is `func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable` and I wanted to keep it as such, I created a protocol:

```
protocol BasicDecoder {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable
}

extension JSONDecoder: BasicDecoder {}
```

And I made `JSONDecoder` respects it (and since it already does...)

Now, to play a little and check what could be done, I created a custom one, in the idea of having like you said a XML Decoder, it's basic, and it's just for the fun (ie: do no replicate this at home ^^):

```
struct CustomWithJSONSerialization: BasicDecoder {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
        guard let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else { fatalError() }
        return Attributes(name: dict["name"] as! String) as! T
    }
}
```

So, `init(from:)`:

```
guard let attributesData = Data(base64Encoded: encodedAttributesString) else { fatalError() }
guard let additionalDecoder = decoder.userInfo[.additionalDecoder] as? BasicDecoder else { fatalError() }
self.attributes = try additionalDecoder.decode(Attributes.self, from: attributesData)
```

Let's try it now!

```
var decoder = JSONDecoder()
let additionalDecoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo = [CodingUserInfoKey.additionalDecoder: additionalDecoder]


var decoder2 = JSONDecoder()
let additionalDecoder2 = CustomWithJSONSerialization()
decoder2.userInfo = [CodingUserInfoKey.additionalDecoder: additionalDecoder]


let jsonStr = """
{
"id": 1234,
"attributes": "eyAibmFtZSI6ICJzb21lLXZhbHVlIiB9",
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let value = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: jsonData)
    print("1: \(value)")
    let value2 = try decoder2.decode(Model.self, from: jsonData)
    print("2: \(value2)")
}
catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Output:

```
$> 1: Model(id: 1234, attributes: Quick.Attributes(name: "some-value"))
$> 2: Model(id: 1234, attributes: Quick.Attributes(name: "some-value"))
```

Comment: I have implemented this approach. Thanks for a great answer and write up, I have accepted! 

Answer (score 3):

If `attributes` contains only one key value pair this is the simple solution.

It decodes the base64 encoded string directly as `Data` – this is possible with the  `.base64` data decoding strategy – and deserializes it with traditional `JSONSerialization`. The value is assigned to a member `name` in the `Model` struct.

If the base64 encoded string cannot be decoded a `DecodingError` will be thrown

```
let jsonString = """
{
   "id": 1234,
   "attributes": "eyAibmFtZSI6ICJzb21lLXZhbHVlIiB9",
}
"""

struct Model: Decodable {
    
    let id: Int64
    let name: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, attributes
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .id)
        let attributeData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .attributes)
        guard let attributes = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: attributeData) as? [String:String],
            let attributeName = attributes["name"] else { throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .attributes, in: container, debugDescription: "Attributes isn't eiter a dicionary or has no key name") }
        self.name = attributeName
    }
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .base64
    let result = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: "If attributes contains only one key value pair this is the simple solution."  Unfortunately it does not, the example in the OP is contrived and simplified.

Comment: The suggested solution simply swaps `JSONDecoder` for `JSONSerialization` which isn't really solving the code smell.

Comment: You cannot avoid the *smell* since it's necessary to decode two different levels.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this interesting post](https://stablekernel.com/article/understanding-extending-swift-4-codable/), I came up with a reusable solution.

You can create a new `NestedJSONDecodable` protocol which gets also the `JSONDecoder` in it's initializer:

```
protocol NestedJSONDecodable: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder, using nestedDecoder: JSONDecoder) throws
}
```

Implement the decoder extraction technique (from the aforementioned post) together with a new `decode(_:from:)` function for decoding `NestedJSONDecodable` types:

```
protocol DecoderExtractable {
    func decoder(for data: Data) throws -> Decoder
}

extension JSONDecoder: DecoderExtractable {
    struct DecoderExtractor: Decodable {
        let decoder: Decoder
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            self.decoder = decoder
        }
    }
    
    func decoder(for data: Data) throws -> Decoder {
        return try decode(DecoderExtractor.self, from: data).decoder
    }
    
    func decode<T: NestedJSONDecodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T {
        return try T(from: try decoder(for: data), using: self)
    }
}
```

And change your `Model` struct to conform to `NestedJSONDecodable` protocol instead of `Decodable`:

```
struct Model: NestedJSONDecodable {

    let id: Int64
    let attributes: Attributes

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case attributes
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder, using nestedDecoder: JSONDecoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.id = try container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .id)
        let attributesData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .attributes)
        
        self.attributes = try nestedDecoder.decode(Attributes.self, from: attributesData)
    }
}
```

The rest of your code will remain the same.

Comment: Thank you, this is defintely a good answer (I have upvoted) however I see one drawback in that its not possible to have `Model` as a sub/nested/child entity of another model.

Comment: @OliverPearmain yes, that's definitely something that I did thought of. I like Larme's answer better to be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single decoder as a `static` property of `Model`, configure it once, and use it for all your `Model` decoding needs, both externally and internally.

Unsolicited thought:
Honestly, I would only recommend doing that if you're seeing a measurable loss of CPU time or crazy heap growth from the allocation of additional JSONDecoders… they're not heavyweight objects, less than 128 bytes unless there's some trickery I don't understand (which is pretty common though tbh):

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
malloc_size(Unmanaged.passRetained(decoder).toOpaque()) // 128
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is replacing one problem for another really.  I've already considered using a singleton.